# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus Proof

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, derivatives

Find $f'$ where is $f$ is defined on $[0, 1]$ as indicated: $$f(x) = \int_x^{\sqrt{x}} \frac 1{1+t^3}dt$$
I know that the fundamental theorem is going to be used in this proof, but I'm not really sure where to begin. So any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $g'(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^3}$, then by the FTC,
$$f(x) = \int_x^{\sqrt{x}} g'(t)\,dt=g(\sqrt x)-g(x)$$
then
$$f'(x)=\frac{g'(\sqrt x)}{2\sqrt x}-g'(x)=\frac{1}{2(\sqrt x+x^2)}-\frac{1}{1+x^3}$$

Comment: Thank you, I was definitely over thinking this problem. Great solution man!

Answer (score 3):

We have: $f(x) = \displaystyle \int_{0}^{\sqrt{x}} \dfrac{1}{1+t^3} dt - \displaystyle \int_{0}^x \dfrac{1}{1+t^3} dt$. Apply the fundamental theorem of calculus and the chainrule we arrive at..:

$f'(x) = \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{x}\cdot (1+x\sqrt{x})} - \dfrac{1}{1+x^3} = \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{x} + 2x^2} - \dfrac{1}{1+x^3}$.

Comment: Thank you, yours and Pauly B's answers were both spot on. Thanks again!

Comment: I have another question about a similar topic if you want to help me out?

Comment: Should I post it in a comment or just open up a second question? It seems a little long to just post in a comment.

Comment: You should post it as a second question, then you get more responses.

Comment: Alright I posted it, feel free to check it out. Thanks!